# kernel block in VScode after runing a program that draw a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

i am trying to run this simple program on VsCode but i get a kernel failure that i don't understand.
The program i run is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = [7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]
y = [5, 12, 19, 21, 31, 27, 35]
z = [3, 5, 11, 20, 15, 29, 31]

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

I did not get this fatal error when using plotly with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

import plotly.express as px

x = [7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49]
y = [5, 12, 19, 21, 31, 27, 35]

fig = px.line( x=x, y=y)
fig.show()
```

The error i get is (sorry in french - but it says the kernel died):

```
Le noyau s’est bloqué lors de l’exécution du code dans une cellule active ou une cellule précédente. 
Veuillez vérifier le code dans la ou les cellules pour identifier une cause possible de l’échec. 
Cliquez [ici](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Kernel-crashes) pour plus d’informations. 
Pour plus d’informations, consultez Jupyter log.
```

any help will be helpfull

Comment: Are you using jupyter? If the same code runs in a `.py` script does it give errors? Also try switching kernels.